# Why is mean() so slow?

Tags: r, performance, optimization

Everything is in the question! I just tried to do a bit of optimization, and nailing down the bottle necks, out of curiosity, I tried that:

```
t1 <- rnorm(10)
microbenchmark(
  mean(t1),
  sum(t1)/length(t1),
  times = 10000)
```

and the result is that mean() is 6+ times slower than the computation "by hand"!

Does it stem from the overhead in the code of mean() before the call to the Internal(mean) or is it the C code itself which is slower? Why? Is there a good reason and thus a good use case?

Comment: I saw this discussed briefly here (Section 3): http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages:cran:data.table#method_dispatch_takes_time

Comment: Also, under "Standard and internal functions" on this blog post: http://www.noamross.net/blog/2013/4/25/faster-talk.html

Comment: It also worth looking at @hadley's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386154/is-s4-method-dispatch-slow

Comment: Because it is not the same algorithm than sum(t)/length(t). 
Cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866149/what-algorithm-is-r-using-to-calculate-mean

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is due to the s3 look up for the method, and then the necessary parsing of arguments in mean.default. (and also  the other code in mean)

`sum` and `length` are both Primitive functions. so will be fast (but how are you handling NA values?)

```
t1 <- rnorm(10)
microbenchmark(
  mean(t1),
  sum(t1)/length(t1),
  mean.default(t1),
  .Internal(mean(t1)),
  times = 10000)

Unit: nanoseconds
                expr   min    lq median    uq     max neval
            mean(t1) 10266 10951  11293 11635 1470714 10000
  sum(t1)/length(t1)   684  1027   1369  1711  104367 10000
    mean.default(t1)  2053  2396   2738  2739 1167195 10000
 .Internal(mean(t1))   342   343    685   685   86574 10000
```

The internal bit of `mean` is faster even than `sum`/`length`.

See http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages:cran:data.table#method_dispatch_takes_time ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20131111215528/http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages:cran:data.table#method_dispatch_takes_time)) for more details  (and a data.table solution that avoids `.Internal`).

Note that if we increase the length of the vector, then the primitive approach is fastest

```
t1 <- rnorm(1e7)
microbenchmark(
     mean(t1),
     sum(t1)/length(t1),
     mean.default(t1),
     .Internal(mean(t1)),
+     times = 100)

Unit: milliseconds
                expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
            mean(t1) 25.79873 26.39242 26.56608 26.85523 33.36137   100
  sum(t1)/length(t1) 15.02399 15.22948 15.31383 15.43239 19.20824   100
    mean.default(t1) 25.69402 26.21466 26.44683 26.84257 33.62896   100
 .Internal(mean(t1)) 25.70497 26.16247 26.39396 26.63982 35.21054   100
```

Now method dispatch is only a fraction of the overall "time"  required.

Comment: How do the benchmarks scale according to different length input vectors?

Comment: Any thought on why (with the long vectors) `sum(t1)/length(t2)` is faster than all the others?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien  `base::mean` does two passes over the vector (at C level) to correct for numerical accuracy (see src/summary.c). Btw, data.table optimized mean also does that to retain that nice feature and be exactly the same as base mean. `sum` is a single pass, and `length` is in the vector's header (no loop).

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Thanks! I haven't written any C, but it looks like that second loop's role is +/- to ensure that you get the same accuracy for a vector of numbers in the range 10000000.1 - 10000000.2 as you do for a vector in the range 0.1 - 0.2 (up to an eventual truncation of the result in the first case). Is that about right?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: see my answer and the linked question.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich -- Thanks. I had missed those. Zach's (wife's) answer to the linked question answers my question.

Comment: Thanks for all these nice answers and comment! Nice breakdown of dispatch >> .default overhead >> internal and the variation with vector length.

Answer (score 24):

`mean` is slower than computing "by hand" for several reasons:

1. S3 Method dispatch
2. `NA` handling
3. Error correction

Points 1 and 2 have already been covered.  Point 3 is discussed in [What algorithm is R using to calculate mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17866149/271616).  Basically, `mean` makes 2 passes over the vector in order to correct for floating point errors. `sum` only makes 1 pass over the vector.

Notice that `identical(sum(t1)/length(t1), mean(t1))` may be `FALSE`, due to these precision issues.

```
> set.seed(21); t1 <- rnorm(1e7,,21)
> identical(sum(t1)/length(t1), mean(t1))
[1] FALSE
> sum(t1)/length(t1) - mean(t1)
[1] 2.539201e-16
```

Comment: Does this apply to `rowMeans` and `colMeans` as well?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft: I'm not sure what "this" refers to, so I can't answer "yes" or "no"... :) But `rowMeans` and `colMeans` do not do any error correction.