# Operations on mult-dimensional arrays in R: apply vs data.table vs plyr (parallel)

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, data.table, plyr

In my research work, I normally deal with big 4D arrays (20-200 millions of elements). 
I'm trying to improve the computational speed of my calculations looking for an optimal trade-off between speed and simplicity. I've already did some step forward thanks to SO (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631165/arithmetic-mean-on-a-multidimensional-array-on-r-and-matlab-drastic-difference) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803814/apply-a-function-to-a-multi-dimensional-array-r-vs-matlab))

Now, I'm trying to exploit the latest packages like `data.table` and `plyr`.

Let's start with something like:

```
D = c(100, 1000, 8) #x,y,t
d = array(rnorm(prod(D)), dim = D)
```

I'd like to get for each `x` (first dimension) and `y` (second dimension) the values of `t` that are above the 90th percentile. Let's do that with base R:

```
system.time(
    q1 <- apply(d, c(1,2), function(x) {
        return(x >= quantile(x, .9, names = F))
        })
)
```

On my Macbook it's about ten seconds. And I get back an array as:

```
> dim(q1)
[1]    8  100 1000
```

(`apply` strangely change the order of the dimensions, anyway I don't care now). Now I can `melt` (`reshape2` package) my array and use it into `data.table`:

```
> d_m = melt(d)
> colnames(d_m) = c('x', 'y', 't', 'value')
> d_t = data.table(d_m)
```

Then I do some data.table "magic":

```
system.time({
    q2 = d_t[,q := quantile(value, .9, names = F), by="x,y"][,ev := value > q]
})
```

The computation now takes slightly less than 10 seconds. Now I want to try with `plyr` and `ddply`:

```
system.time({
    q3 <- ddply(d_m, .(x, y), summarise, q = quantile(value, .9, names = F))
})
```

Now, it takes 60 seconds. If I move to `dplyr` I can do the same calculation again in ten seconds.

However, my question is the following: what would you do to do the same calculation in a faster way? If I consider a larger matrix (say 20 times bigger) I obtain a faster computation using data.table wrt the `apply` function but however at the same order of magnitude (14 minutes vs 10 minutes). 
Any comment is really appreciated...

**EDIT**

I've implemented the quantile function in c++ using `Rcpp` speeding up the computation of eight times.

Comment: I suspect your bottle neck is `quantile` and not the function used for "split-apply-combine". Profile your code. Possibly you'd need to write a faster `quantile` function (it's implemented in R currently, thus not very fast). Have a look at Rcpp.

Comment: You're right. I've just spent one hour to learn how to replicate the R quantile algorithm with Rcpp. I have obtained a speed-up of eight times.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @roland, one possible solution to speed up the code was to implement a faster version of `quantile` function. I spent one hour to learn how to do that using `Rcpp` and the running time decreased eight times. I've implemented the `type 7` version of the quantile algorithm (default choice). 
We are still far from the MATLAB performance (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803814/apply-a-function-to-a-multi-dimensional-array-r-vs-matlab)) but in my case this is an impressive step forward. I am not proud of the Rcpp code I have written so far, I didn't have the time to polish it. Anyway, it works (I checked the results with the R function) and so if you are interested you can download it from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1249990/quantileC.R).