# Looking for faster way to implement logSumExp across multidimensional array

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I have a line in some R code I am writing that is quite slow. It applies logSumExp across a 4 dimensional array using the apply command. I'm wondering are there ways to speed it up!

Reprex: (this might take 10seconds or more to run)

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(matrixStats)

array4d <- array( runif(5*500*50*5 ,-1,0),
                  dim = c(5, 500, 50, 5) )
microbenchmark(
    result <- apply(array4d, c(1,2,3), logSumExp)
)
```

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The otherwise great solution from @Miff was causing my code to crash with certain datasets as infinities were being produced which I eventually figured out was due to an underflow problem which can be avoided by using the 'logSumExp trick': https://www.xarg.org/2016/06/the-log-sum-exp-trick-in-machine-learning/

Taking inspiration from @Miff 's code, and the R `apply()` function, I made a new function to gives faster calculations while avoiding the underflow issue. Not quite as fast as @Miff 's solution however. Posting in case it helps others

```
apply_logSumExp <- function (X) {
    MARGIN <- c(1, 2, 3) # fixing the margins as have not tested other dims
    dl <- length(dim(X)) # get length of dim
    d <- dim(X) # get dim
    dn <- dimnames(X) # get dimnames
    ds <- seq_len(dl) # makes sequences of length of dims
    d.call <- d[-MARGIN]    # gets index of dim not included in MARGIN
    d.ans <- d[MARGIN]  # define dim for answer array
    s.call <- ds[-MARGIN] # used to define permute
    s.ans <- ds[MARGIN]     # used to define permute
    d2 <- prod(d.ans)   # length of results object
    
    newX <- aperm(X, c(s.call, s.ans)) # permute X such that dims omitted from calc are first dim
    dim(newX) <- c(prod(d.call), d2) # voodoo. Preserves ommitted dim dimension but collapses the rest into 1
    
    maxes <- colMaxs(newX)
    ans <- maxes + log(colSums(exp( sweep(newX, 2, maxes, "-"))) )
    ans <- array(ans, d.ans)
    
    return(ans)
}

 > microbenchmark(
+     res1 <- apply(array4d, c(1,2,3), logSumExp),
+     res2 <- log(rowSums(exp(array4d), dims=3)),
+     res3 <- apply_logSumExp(array4d)
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
                                          expr        min         lq       mean    median        uq       max
 res1 <- apply(array4d, c(1, 2, 3), logSumExp) 176.286670 213.882443 247.420334 236.44593 267.81127 486.41072
  res2 <- log(rowSums(exp(array4d), dims = 3))   4.664907   5.821601   7.588448   5.97765   7.47814  30.58002
              res3 <- apply_logSumExp(array4d)  12.119875  14.673011  19.635265  15.20385  18.30471  90.59859
 neval cld
   100   c
   100 a  
   100  b
```

Answer (score 2):

`rowSums` is a less general version of apply that is optimised for speed when adding up, so this can be used to speed up the calculation. Note the caveat in the helpfile `?rowSums` if it's important to maintain a difference in your calculations between `NA` and `NaN`.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(matrixStats)

array4d <- array( runif(5*500*50*5 ,-1,0),
                  dim = c(5, 500, 50, 5) )
microbenchmark(
  result <- apply(array4d, c(1,2,3), logSumExp),
  result2 <- log(rowSums(exp(array4d), dims=3))
)


# Unit: milliseconds
#                                            expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
# result <- apply(array4d, c(1, 2, 3), logSumExp) 249.4757 274.8227 305.24680 297.30245 328.90610 405.5038   100
# result2 <- log(rowSums(exp(array4d), dims = 3))  31.8783  32.7493  35.20605  33.01965  33.45205 133.3257   100

all.equal(result, result2)

#TRUE
```

This results in a 9x speed increase on my computer

Comment: Indeed this gave a 37x speedup on my machine! But, I'm concerned about precision, it gives TRUE for ```all.equal()```, but not for ```identical()```. I was trying to implement a variation of this answer, but rowLogSumExps does not behave the same way as rowMeans so I can't make it work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18633390/2498193

Comment: @user2498193 In general you wouldn't expect two different ways of calculating it to give the same answer because of machine precision and rounding. `range(result - result2)` gives numbers around 10^-16, so I'd suggest that the differences are negligible

Comment: [Obligatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) on why the numbers are not quite the same

Comment: I had another query that I thought merited a follow on question if you have time (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894184/looking-for-speedups-for-multidimensional-array-code) - but if not thank you for your help thus far!

Comment: Alas! This has come back to bite me - with extreme data this is producing infinities, whilst the original does not

Comment: So I figured out this is due to the so called underflow issue with logSumExp. @Miff, I combined your magic with some dimensional voodoo inspired by the ```array()``` function code, and the 'logSumExp' trick (https://www.xarg.org/2016/06/the-log-sum-exp-trick-in-machine-learning/) to get a version that's not quite as fast as yours, but does not suffer this underflow problem. Posting as a new answer!