# Calculating pvalue within a huge data frame takes very long

Tags: r, performance, dplyr

I am trying to calculate `p.values` with a students t-test within a very huge data frame in the long data format. Since my original data frame has about  lines within the data frame, the calculation of the p.values takes very long (took about 100 Minutes).

I am trying to speed the process up, but I am not sure if the data frame is the best format to increase speed or if I should reshape the data and maybe use a `matrix`.

Here is some reproducible example with a little data frame and a benchmark at the end.

```
library(dplyr)

my.t.test <- function (x, y = NULL) {
  nx <- length(x)
  mx <- mean(x)
  vx <- var(x)
  ny <- length(y)
  my <- mean(y)
  vy <- var(y)
  stderrx <- sqrt(vx/nx)
  stderry <- sqrt(vy/ny)
  stderr <- sqrt(stderrx^2 + stderry^2)
  df <- stderr^4/(stderrx^4/(nx - 1) + stderry^4/(ny - 1))
  tstat <- (mx - my - 0)/stderr
  pval <- 2 * pt(-abs(tstat), df)
  return(pval)
}

cont <- c("A", "B")
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(id=rep(1:1000, each=8),
                  replicate=1:4,
                  A=rnorm(8000, mean=26, sd=5),
                  B=rnorm(8000, mean=25, sd=7))

completeDF <- function() {
  df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(Comparison=paste(cont, collapse=' - '),
            p.value=t.test(get(cont[1]), get(cont[2]))$p.value,
            log10.p.value=-log10(p.value),
            log2.foldchange=mean(get(cont[1]), na.rm=TRUE) - mean(get(cont[2]), na.rm=TRUE)
  )}
noPvalue <- function() {
  df1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(Comparison=paste(cont, collapse=' - '),
              log2.foldchange=mean(get(cont[1]), na.rm=TRUE) - mean(get(cont[2]), na.rm=TRUE)
    )}
myPvalue <- function() {
  df1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(Comparison=paste(cont, collapse=' - '),
              p.value=my.t.test(get(cont[1]), get(cont[2])),
              log10.p.value=-log10(p.value),
              log2.foldchange=mean(get(cont[1]), na.rm=TRUE) - mean(get(cont[2]), na.rm=TRUE)
    )}
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  completeDF(), noPvalue(), myPvalue()
)
```

My benchmark:

```
Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 completeDF() 358.38330 365.09423 424.60255 369.20453 377.40354 655.2009   100
   noPvalue()  57.42996  58.89978  81.86222  59.66851  60.96582 337.2346   100
   myPvalue() 216.04812 220.98277 318.09568 224.19516 493.74908 609.4516   100
```

So with my very reduced (no test, etc) t.test function, I save already some time. But I am wondering if this can be further improved by vectorising somehow.

Comment: I believe there is an obviuos place where to make it (slightly?) faster: you compute `stderrx` and `stderry` but never use the square roots, you later square those square roots and raise them to 4th powers. Maybe something like `varx <- vx/nx` will save some time.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, just tested it and the median is a bit smaller. Just a bit.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I was also trying to remove the whole `<-` within the function and writing it basically as a single line, because I thought the writing into memory is taking some time, but this was slower in the end... I basically used the `stats:::t.test.default()` function and just removed all the parts I don't use.

Comment: Your data set has a replicate column that I don't see you using. What is it? Should these be paired t-tests?

Comment: No, it is not a paired t-test. This column is just for tracking from which sample the values arise, I could also delete it for this calculation.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, replace `mean(x)` with `sum(x) / length(x)`, as [`mean` is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18604406/4891738).

Then when I profile the updated `my.t.test`, I find that 80% of its execution time is spent in `var`. So I replace `var` with an Rcpp implementation.

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction("double var_cpp (NumericVector x, double xc) {
  size_t n = (size_t)x.size();
  double z1 = 0.0, z2 = 0.0, *p = &x[0], *q = &x[n];
  if (n & 2) {z1 = (*p - xc) * (*p - xc); p++;}
  for (; p < q; p += 2) {
    z1 += (p[0] - xc) * (p[0] - xc);
    z2 += (p[1] - xc) * (p[1] - xc);
    }
  z1 = (z1 + z2) / (double)(n - 1);
  return z1;
  }")

library(microbenchmark)
x <- runif(1e+7)
xc <- sum(x) / length(x)
microbenchmark(var_cpp(x, xc), var(x))
#Unit: milliseconds
#           expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max
# var_cpp(x, xc)  20.71985  20.76298  21.00832  20.80576  20.87323  25.85723
#         var(x) 109.61120 109.78513 111.92657 109.89077 114.21301 121.98907
```

`sum` can be boosted as well.

```
cppFunction("double sum_cpp (NumericVector x) {
  size_t n = (size_t)x.size();
  double z1 = 0.0, z2 = 0.0, *p = &x[0], *q = &x[n];
  if (n & 2) z1 = *p++;
  for (; p < q; p += 2) {z1 += p[0]; z2 += p[1];}
  z1 = (z1 + z2);
  return z1;
  }")

microbenchmark(sum_cpp(x), sum(x))
#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# sum_cpp(x) 15.58856 15.63613 15.70195 15.67847 15.69998 18.14852   100
#     sum(x) 30.13504 30.20687 30.23993 30.23877 30.26721 30.40525   100
```

So these give:

```
my.t.test.cpp <- function (x, y = NULL) {
  nx <- length(x)
  mx <- sum_cpp(x) / nx
  vx <- var_cpp(x, mx)
  ny <- length(y)
  my <- sum_cpp(y) / ny
  vy <- var_cpp(y, my)
  stderrx <- sqrt(vx/nx)
  stderry <- sqrt(vy/ny)
  stderr <- sqrt(stderrx^2 + stderry^2)
  df <- stderr^4/(stderrx^4/(nx - 1) + stderry^4/(ny - 1))
  tstat <- (mx - my - 0)/stderr
  pval <- 2 * pt(-abs(tstat), df)
  return(pval)
  }
```

---

#### On [Martin Morgan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51968620/4891738)

Thanks Martin for converting the `dplyr` code to R base code. Now I can see better what OP is doing.

Also thanks Martin for adding `fcpp` in his revision. I have also written down that `fcpp` myself (close to his). My benchmarking with datasets of different sizes shows that `fcpp` and `f2.2` have the same performance (as his benchmarking shows).

But, we are both bottlenecked by that `factor` function at the beginning. For OP's data `df1` where grouping variable `id` is `1:1000`, we can do `class(id) <- "factor"; levels(id) <- 1:1000`. In general we might use `as.factor` which is helpful if grouping variable is already a factor in the data frame. See [R: Why use as.factor() instead of just factor()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39279238/4891738).

Comment: I implemented a more complete C++ solution, where the group sums / sums-of-squares are calculated in one call rather than once per group.

Answer (score 6):

The mean and variance calculations need to be done by group, but the t-test and p-value calculation can be vectorized.

```
my.t.test.2 <- function(grp, x, y) {
    grp <- factor(grp)

    x_g <- split(x, grp)
    x_n <- lengths(x_g)
    x_mean <- vapply(x_g, mean, numeric(1))
    x_var <- vapply(x_g, var, numeric(1))

    y_g <- split(y, grp)
    y_n <- lengths(y_g)
    y_mean <- vapply(y_g, mean, numeric(1))
    y_var <- vapply(y_g, var, numeric(1))

    x_se2 <- x_var / x_n
    y_se2 <- y_var / y_n
    se <- sqrt(x_se2 + y_se2)
    tstat <- (x_mean - y_mean) / se
    df <- se^4 / (x_se2^2 / (x_n - 1L) + (y_se2^2) / (y_n - 1L))

    2 * pt(-abs(tstat), df)
}
```

One can try and be super clever by avoiding dispatch (the 'reason' give for slowness of `mean()`) and minimizing redundant calculation, e.g., of the lengths of each group.

```
my.t.test.2.1 <- compiler::cmpfun(function(grp, x, y) {
    grp <- factor(grp)

    x_g <- split.default(x, grp)
    n <- lengths(x_g)
    n1 <- n - 1L
    x_mean <- vapply(x_g, mean.default, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    x_var <- vapply(x_g, var, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)

    y_g <- split.default(y, grp)
    y_mean <- vapply(y_g, mean.default, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    y_var <- vapply(y_g, var, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)

    x_se2 <- x_var / n
    y_se2 <- y_var / n
    se <- sqrt(x_se2 + y_se2)
    tstat <- (x_mean - y_mean) / se
    df <- se^4 / ((x_se2^2 + y_se2^2) / n1)

    2 * pt(-abs(tstat), df)
})
```

The canonical and other solutions can be wrapped to provide the same output

```
f0 <- function(df)
    df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(p.value = t.test(A, B)$p.value)

f1 <- function(df)
    df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(p.value = my.t.test(A, B))

f2 <- function(df)
    tibble(id = unique(df$id), p.value = my.t.test.2(df$id, df$A, df$B))

f2.1 <- function(df)
    tibble(id = unique(df$id), p.value = my.t.test.2.1(df$id, df$A, df$B))
```

`f2.1()` produces the same result as the canonical implementation and is about twice as fast; worrying about the speed of `mean()`, etc (`f2()` vs. `f2.1()`) seems mostly to be misguided

```
> all.equal.default(f0(df1), f2.1(df1))
[1] TRUE
> microbenchmark(f0(df1), f1(df1), f2(df1), f2.1(df1), times = 5)
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   f0(df1) 374.2819 379.7749 380.8365 380.0094 381.2368 388.8794     5
   f1(df1) 249.6502 250.2525 251.8813 252.1965 253.3444 253.9630     5
   f2(df1) 154.1152 158.3243 159.8277 159.1076 162.7602 164.8311     5
 f2.1(df1) 151.0032 151.0149 152.3900 152.8105 153.2840 153.8373     5
```

For me the C++ implementation

```
my.t.test.cpp <- function (x, y = NULL) {
    nx <- length(x)
    mx <- sum_cpp(x) / nx
    vx <- var_cpp(x, mx)
    ny <- length(y)
    my <- sum_cpp(y) / ny
    vy <- var_cpp(y, my)
    stderrx <- sqrt(vx/nx)
    stderry <- sqrt(vy/ny)
    stderr <- sqrt(stderrx^2 + stderry^2)
    df <- stderr^4/(stderrx^4/(nx - 1) + stderry^4/(ny - 1))
    tstat <- (mx - my - 0)/stderr
    pval <- 2 * pt(-abs(tstat), df)
    return(pval)
}

fcpp <- function(df)
    df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(p.value = my.t.test.cpp(A, B))
```

produces results equal to the canonical and clocks in at about 100 ms.

Profiling the 2.1 solution shows that most of the time is spent inside `var()`, where there is a call to `stopifnot()` as well as a argument matching call

```
> var
function (x, y = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, use) 
{
    ...
    na.method <- pmatch(use, c("all.obs", "complete.obs", "pairwise.complete.obs", 
        "everything", "na.or.complete"))
    ...
    if (is.data.frame(x)) 
        x <- as.matrix(x)
    else stopifnot(is.atomic(x))
    ... 
    .Call(C_cov, x, y, na.method, FALSE)
}
<bytecode: 0x5e1a440>
<environment: namespace:stats>

> Rprof(); x <- my.t.test.2.1(df1$id, df1$A, df1$B); Rprof(NULL); summaryRprof()
$by.self
                      self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"withCallingHandlers"      0.04    28.57       0.08     57.14
"tryCatchList"             0.04    28.57       0.04     28.57
"vapply"                   0.02    14.29       0.14    100.00
"stopifnot"                0.02    14.29       0.12     85.71
"match.call"               0.02    14.29       0.02     14.29

$by.total
                      total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"vapply"                    0.14    100.00      0.02    14.29
"my.t.test.2.1"             0.14    100.00      0.00     0.00
"stopifnot"                 0.12     85.71      0.02    14.29
"FUN"                       0.12     85.71      0.00     0.00
"withCallingHandlers"       0.08     57.14      0.04    28.57
"tryCatchList"              0.04     28.57      0.04    28.57
"tryCatch"                  0.04     28.57      0.00     0.00
"match.call"                0.02     14.29      0.02    14.29

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 0.14
```

So in the pursuit of speed one might avoid the argument checks and call the C function directly

```
my.t.test.2.2 <- compiler::cmpfun(function(grp, x, y) {
    var <- function(x)
        .Call(stats:::C_cov, x, NULL, 4L, FALSE)
    grp <- factor(grp)

    x_g <- split.default(x, grp)
    n <- lengths(x_g)
    n1 <- n - 1L
    x_mean <- vapply(x_g, mean.default, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    x_var <- vapply(x_g, var, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)

    y_g <- split.default(y, grp)
    y_mean <- vapply(y_g, mean.default, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    y_var <- vapply(y_g, var, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)

    x_se2 <- x_var / n
    y_se2 <- y_var / n
    se <- sqrt(x_se2 + y_se2)
    tstat <- (x_mean - y_mean) / se
    df <- se^4 / ((x_se2^2 + y_se2^2) / n1)

    2 * pt(-abs(tstat), df)
})

f2.2 <- function(df)
    tibble(id = unique(df$id), p.value = my.t.test.2.2(df$id, df$A, df$B))
```

This turns out to be quite performant.

```
> all.equal.default(f0(df1), f2.2(df1))
[1] TRUE
> microbenchmark(
+     f0(df1), f1(df1), f2(df1), f2.1(df1), f2.2(df1), fcpp(df1),
+     times = 5
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
      expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
   f0(df1) 378.61985 379.25525 393.38371 379.56797 386.2806 443.19488     5
   f1(df1) 250.99802 252.45281 253.55140 253.34249 255.2801 255.68362     5
   f2(df1) 156.76073 158.63126 159.63693 160.33446 161.2260 161.23216     5
 f2.1(df1) 146.64555 148.28773 151.17250 151.38536 153.9363 155.60751     5
 f2.2(df1)  25.24441  25.62982  27.50898  26.11755  30.0836  30.46951     5
 fcpp(df1) 104.20851 104.50396 105.19383 104.62905 104.7876 107.84006     5
```

We can use the C++ implementation of variance calculation instead of the call to R's computation with

```
my.t.test.2.2.cpp <- compiler::cmpfun(function(grp, x, y) {
    grp <- factor(grp)

    x_g <- split.default(x, grp)
    n <- lengths(x_g)
    n1 <- n - 1L
    x_mean <- vapply(x_g, mean.default, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    x_var <- unlist(Map(var_cpp, x_g, x_mean))

    y_g <- split.default(y, grp)
    y_mean <- vapply(y_g, mean.default, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    y_var <- unlist(Map(var_cpp, y_g, y_mean))

    x_se2 <- x_var / n
    y_se2 <- y_var / n
    se <- sqrt(x_se2 + y_se2)
    tstat <- (x_mean - y_mean) / se
    df <- se^4 / ((x_se2^2 + y_se2^2) / n1)

    2 * pt(-abs(tstat), df)
})

f2.2.cpp <- function(df)
    tibble(id = unique(df$id), p.value = my.t.test.2.2.cpp(df$id, df$A, df$B))
```

for comparable performance

```
> microbenchmark(f2.2(df1), f2.2.cpp(df1), times = 20)
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
     f2.2(df1) 25.11237 25.69622 30.27956 26.35570 29.81884 87.34955    20
 f2.2.cpp(df1) 24.88787 25.25171 26.80836 25.43498 29.06338 30.80012    20
```

I'm not sure which is more of a hack -- writing your own C++ code for the variance, or calling R's C code directly.

A faster C++ solution calculates the group mean and variance in a single call

```
cppFunction('List doit(IntegerVector group, NumericVector x) {
  int n_grp = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < group.size(); ++i)
      n_grp = group[i] > n_grp ? group[i] : n_grp;

  std::vector<int> n(n_grp);
  std::vector<double> sum(n_grp), sumsq(n_grp);
  for (int i = 0; i < group.size(); ++i) {
      n[ group[i] - 1 ] += 1;
      sum[ group[i] - 1 ] += x[i];
      sumsq[ group[i] - 1 ] += x[i] * x[i];
  }
  NumericVector mean(n_grp), var(n_grp);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n.size(); ++i) {
      mean[i] = sum[i] / n[i];
      var[i] = (sumsq[i] - sum[i] * mean[i]) / (n[i] - 1);
  }
  return List::create(_["n"]=n[0], _["mean"]=mean, _["var"]=var);
}')

my.t.test.2.3.cpp <- compiler::cmpfun(function(grp, x, y) {
    x <- doit(grp, x)
    y <- doit(grp, y)

    x_se2 <- x$var / x$n
    y_se2 <- y$var / y$n
    se <- sqrt(x_se2 + y_se2)
    tstat <- (x$mean - y$mean) / se
    df <- se^4 / ((x_se2^2 + y_se2^2) / (x$n - 1L))

    2 * pt(-abs(tstat), df)
})

f2.3.cpp <- function(df)
    tibble(
        id = unique(df$id),
        p.value = my.t.test.2.3.cpp(df$id, df$A, df$B)
    )
```

and this is fast

```
> all.equal.default(f0(df1), f2.3.cpp(df1))
[1] TRUE
> microbenchmark(f2.2(df1), f2.2.cpp(df1), f2.3.cpp(df1), times = 50)
Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max
     f2.2(df1) 24.743364 25.445833 28.032135 25.873117 29.191020 88.642771
 f2.2.cpp(df1) 24.122380 24.867212 26.012985 25.369963 25.897866 30.783544
 f2.3.cpp(df1)  2.831635  2.946094  3.101408  2.992049  3.073788  7.191572
 neval
    50
    50
    50
>
```

Another alternative is the Bioconductor package [genefilter](https://bioconductor.org/packages/genefilter)`::rowttests()`, which requires a matrix

```
set.seed(1)
m1 <- cbind(
    matrix(rnorm(8000, mean = 26, sd = 5), ncol=8, byrow = TRUE),
    matrix(rnorm(8000, mean = 25, sd = 7), ncol=8, byrow = TRUE)
)

f4 <- function(m1)
    genefilter::rowttests(m1, factor(rep(1:2, each=8)))
```

and is also fast

```
> microbenchmark(f2.3.cpp(df1), f4(m1), times=50)
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 f2.3.cpp(df1) 2.760877 2.796542 2.877030 2.845795 2.895441 3.286143    50
        f4(m1) 1.335288 1.359007 1.397601 1.377544 1.412606 1.693340    50
```

(some of the difference is in creating the tibble).

Comment: I should have used the time at CSAMA more special coding and optimisation! Thanks Martin, this is performing very very well.

Comment: I added `fcpp()` which is the C++ implementation. It still uses iteration by group for all parts of the calculation, rather than just mean / variance calculation.

Comment: I'd use `match(group, unique(group))` to make sure that the ids are sequential integers; this will be fast (enough).